# Cannot access attribute with XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I have got the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<questions>
<question topic="net">
    <questiontext>Which of the following applies to TCP?</questiontext>
    <answers correct="true">
        <answer correct="true">reliable</answer>
        <answer correct="false">connectionless</answer>
        <answer correct="true">connection-oriented</answer>
        <answer correct="false">datagram-based</answer>         
    </answers>
</question>
</questions>
```

and I am trying to parse it with the following code to get the value of the "correct" attributes on the "answer" elements

```
private ArrayList<MCAnswer> readAnswers(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

    // create an ArrayList to which MCAnswers will be added below
    ArrayList<MCAnswer> answers = new ArrayList<MCAnswer>();

    // starting at the <answers> element...
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "answers");

    // loop through the individual <answer> elements
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }

        // read in answer text
        String answerText = readText(parser);

        // TODO how to get value of "correct" attribute of <answer>? 

        //debugging variables
        int numOfAttrs = parser.getAttributeCount(); //returns -1, not right!
        String element = parser.getName(); //returns "answer", right!

        String attr = parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "correct"); //returns null, not right!

    }
    return answers;
}
```

My problem is with 
    String attr = parser.getAttributeValue(ns, "correct");
I expect it to return the value "true" or "false" but it returns null, as if the parser could not find the attribute, getAttributeValues() above that also returns -1 (IndexOutOfBoundsError?) but it seems I am on the correct tag as getName() and the node text return the correct values.

What am I doing wrong that's stopping me from accessing the attribute?

Comment: try using with dom Parser

Comment: What does `parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "answers");` return? Also, I don't see any code moving the parser from `answers` to  the first `answer`. Finally, assuming everything from the previous two questions goes as planned, `while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG)` will be false for the first `</answer>` the parser encounters. That is, unless `readText(parser)` consumes that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - it's to move parsing the attribute before parsing the text node of the element. Once the parser steps down into the element, it cannot access the attributes any more.